# Laravel blade regex image and output it?

Tags: laravel, twitter, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hi I have twitter api working to output details on the page however, this
field:

> {{ $item['text'] }}

Gives me something like this:

```
RT @JacksSmokehouse: Don't forget #HappyHour tomorrow until 6pm - #loveJacks @live_oldham #OldhamHour #YouDontKnowJack https://twitter.com/shorturl, (with t.co)
```

So the image https:// I want to actually display it? is it possible to write in blade template a regex, something like this:

for each {{$item['text']}} take the url if there is any and output it below the text? can be a different variable.

Here's my full code:

```
<div>
@if(!empty($twitterItems))
    @foreach($twitterItems as $key => $item)
        {{ $item['text'] }}
        @if(!empty($item['extended_entities']['media']))
            @foreach($item['extended_entities']['media'] as $image)
                <img src="{{ $image['media_url_https'] }}" style="width:100px;">
            @endforeach
        @endif
        {{ $item['favorite_count'] }}
        {{ $item['retweet_count'] }}
        {{ $item['created_at'] }}
    @endforeach
@else
    There are no data.
@endif
```